# regex to find specific exif key

Tags: vb.net

what would be the regex to get a specific keyvalue from exif data

sample data

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 8.60
File Name                       : IMG_0014.MOV
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 19 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:07:19 12:03:22-10:00
Software (und-AU)               : 6.1.3
Model (und-AU)                  : iPhone 4S
Avg Bitrate                     : 22 Mbps
Image Size                      : 1920x1080
Rotation                        : 90
```

Comment: I notice your sample data begins with "ExifTool". Does this mean you are using [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to extract the data, and you want to parse the resulting text output?

Comment: In that case, what have you tried, and in what way did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

A regex is not suitable to get arbitrary key values from exif data.

The values in exif data are not always text. Some are integer of varying lengths, signed or unsigned, some are rational (two integers to be divided to get a floating point), and the byte order of integers is specified in the file. In addition, some values referenced by a pointer.

http://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html

Comment: It's not simple. You can read the binary file and process it "manually". This may help: http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF  In addition, you may be able to use a library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/exiflibrary/

Comment: the lib is only for image files , i want to get data from video files